# Storing image in a folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a small piece of code that will get the request input file from the form and will move it to a folder. Here it is:

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads';

$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

Yes, the code above works but then what I wanted to do is each time I upload an image, it will have a unique name so it wouldn't overwrite any picture in the folder. For now this is what I did:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$rand = md5(generateRandomString());
$filename = $rand."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
$upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

This will output something like `7c724458520a11c68747793c86554127_Jellyfish.jpg` but it looks untidy. Is there a trick for this? Thank you.

Comment: remove `md5` on here `$rand = md5(generateRandomString());`

Comment: Why not just check if the file exist and if it does add _1 to the new file name?

Comment: Yes @Abdulla is right. Because you generate a random string then hashed it.

Comment: @aldrin27 You may want to check my answer and suggest more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove `md5` on here `$rand = md5(generateRandomString());`

> Because **you generate a random string then hashed it**

Comment: You may want to check my answer and suggest more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more common ways to create unique file names is using time.

Also you could check this:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-generate-long-unique-name-for-filename

Comment: What is the user wants to use file names using `ID's`?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve my problem. First by removing `md5` as suggested by `Abdulla` and then by doing this:

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$rand = generateRandomString();

$file_list = File::files('uploads'); //returns an array of all of the files in a given directory.

do {
  $filename = $rand."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
} while(in_array("uploads/".$filename, $file_list)); //keep generating a string until it doesn't exist in the given directory.

$upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename); //move the file
```